# Bind method name using knockout foreach binding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to bind method name with list element using knockout foreach. Method should get called on `mousedown`, but method name is in string and I don;t know how to use it.

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/egbh0x3z/)

> Javascript

```
  var model = {};
        var data1 = [{ Name: "hi", Method: "a" }, { Name: "hello", Method: "b" }, { Name: "bye", Method: "c" }];

        model.data = ko.observableArray(data1);

        function a() {
            alert('i am a');
        }

        function b() {
            alert('i am b');
        }


        function c() {
            alert('i am c');
        }

        ko.applyBindings(model);
```

> Html

```
  <ul data-bind="foreach: data">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="text: Name, event: { mousedown: Method }"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to call different functions for the different items?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define your function inside of your `Viewmodel` definition as shown 
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/egbh0x3z/1/)

i.e. You need to use it as::

```
  var model = {};
            var data1 = [{ Name: "hi", Method: 
            function a() {
                alert('i am a');
            } }];

            model.data = ko.observableArray(data1);



            ko.applyBindings(model);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egbh0x3z/2/

Just checkout the JSFiddle links those I sent above.

Comment: but i need to insert function as a string . var data1 = [{ Name: "hi", Method: 
            "function a() {
                alert('i am a');
            }" }];

Comment: What you want to achieve through function is achieved.
what else you want?

Comment: actually my modal is in json form so function is in string format.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

```
var model = {};
var data1 = [
        { Name: "hi", Method: "a" }, 
        { Name: "hello", Method: "b" }, 
        { Name: "bye", Method: "c" }
];

model.data = ko.observableArray(data1);
model.Method = function(str){
    if(str == 'a'){
        a()
    }else if(str == 'b'){
        b()
    }else{
        c()
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(model);


function a() {
    alert('i am a');
}

function b() {
    alert('i am b');
}


function c() {
    alert('i am c');
}
```

And view

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: data">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="text: Name, event: { mousedown: $root.Method.bind($data,Method) }"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You pass the method like this:

```
<label data-bind="text: Name, event: { mousedown: Method }"></label>
```

and your model should be like this:

```
var data1 = [{ Name: "hi", Method: a }, { Name: "hello", Method: b }, { Name: "bye", Method: c }];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egbh0x3z/4/

Answer (score 0):

here is the required [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/egbh0x3z/5/)

you just need removed double qquotes while writing function name.

```
var model = {};
        var data1 = [{ Name: "hi", Method: a }, { Name: "hello", Method: b }, { Name: "bye", Method: c }];

        model.data = ko.observableArray(data1);

        function a() {
            alert('i am a');
        }

        function b() {
            alert('i am b');
        }


        function c() {
            alert('i am c');
        }

        ko.applyBindings(model);
```